# How can I add an md-icon next to an input like in angular material 1?

Tags: angular-material2

How can I add *md-icon* elements next to inputs like in angular material 1 and this screenshot from google contacts:

Google contacts edit form

[image]

I know I can use mdPrefix but I like this style better.

Code example:

```
<md-input-container>
<md-icon mdPrefix>star</md-icon>
<input placeholder="Test" mdInput />
</md-input-container>
```

The icon inside the input field and I'd like it to be next to it:

[image: Icon inside input field]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce the issue **in the question itself**, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Using some css tricks, I was able make something close to the the provided screenshot.

[image]

css to position icons:

```
/deep/ .mat-icon {
    color: grey;
    width: 24px;
    margin: 20px 40px 0 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <md-icon >email</md-icon>
  <md-input-container >
    <input mdInput placeholder="Email">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Code [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZWQ2XvVbF1TTxClE9W1o?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, that css works great. But I was hoping there was an official way of doing this with the framework. In angular material 1 it was simply done by adding an md-icon inside the md-input-container.